# Celery, Django and S3 Default Storage causes file reading issues

Tags: python, django, django-storage

I have a process whereby a web server injects a file (via an upload), saves that file to S3 using default_storages, then creates a task for that file to be processed by the backend via celery.

```
def upload_file(request):
  path = 'uploads/my_file.csv'
  with default_storage.open(path, 'w') as file:
    file.write(request.FILES['upload'].read().decode('utf-8-sig'))
  process_upload.delay(path)
  return HttpResponse()

@shared_task
def process_upload(path):
  with default_storage.open(path, 'r') as file:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(file.read(1024]))
    file.seek(0)
    reader = csv.DictReader(content, dialect=dialect)
    for row in reader:
      # etc...
```

The problem is that, although I'm using text-mode explicitly on writing and read, when I read the file it comes through as `bytes`, which the csv library cannot handle. Is there any way around this without reading in and decoding the whole file in memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you need to add the `b` (binary mode) to the `open` call:

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files):

> `'b'` appended to the mode opens the file in **binary mode**: now the data is read and written in the form of bytes objects. **This mode should be used for all files that don’t contain text**.

```
@shared_task
def process_upload(path):
  with default_storage.open(path, 'rb') as file:
      # Rest of your code goes here.
```